# How to mock beans Autowired on service layer in @WebMvcTest

Tags: spring-boot, testing, mockito, springmockito

I am testing a REST API's in Spring boot gradle app, my mocked service using @MockBean is returning null. This mocked service return null if there are some beans Autowired in service class(I used constructor injection).

Here is sample Code(Not compiled, only for understanding)

```java
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/xxx")
    class TestController {

        private RetriveDataService retriveDataService;

        public TestControllerx(RetriveDataService retriveDataService) {
            this.retriveDataService = retriveDataService;
        }

        @PostMapping(value = "/yyy")
        public MyResponseModel myMethod(@RequestBody MyRequestModel model) {

            return retriveDataService.retriveData(model);
        }

    }

    @Service
    class RetriveDataService {

        private TokenService tokenService;

        public RetriveDataService(TokenService tokenService) {
            this.tokenService = tokenService;
        }

        public MyResponseModel retriveData(MyRequestModel model) {
            String accessToken = tokenService.getToken().getAccessToken();

            return retriveData(model, accessToken);
        }

    }

    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @WebMvcTest(TestController.class)
    public class TestControllerTest {

        @Autowired
        private MockMvc mvc;

        @Autowired
        private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

        @MockBean
        private RetriveDataService retriveDataService;

        @Test
        public void testRetriveData() throws Exception {

            mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/xxx/yyy").content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new MyRequestModel()))
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)).andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                    .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));
        }

    }
```

When I run this test, i am getting following output(If my service do not need another bean, I am getting expected output)

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = []
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

Due to this response i facing problem on line .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));. also when i check response body(as body is also a null)

Sample project to reproduce the issue is [here](https://github.com/parshuram-patil/testing-with-mockito)

Comment: can you provide some code of your example.So we can understand your problem properly.

Comment: possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53780625/testing-mockbean-null

Comment: The default behavior of mocks is to return `null`... You must register behavior on mocks what to do if a method is being called, if you don't do that it will return `null` or empty collections etc.

Comment: Guys, Please have a loop at updated problem statement.

Comment: @M.Deinum
do you mean we should use BDD like when().thenReturn()? 
I tried with this too. 
And if it is the case that you said, how to handle such scenarios, its basic use case of verifying contents of response body.

Comment: How you register the behavior doesn't matter, fact is you need it else ou will get null as a result.

Comment: You don't define any `@MockBean` in your test. In particular, you dont provide a MockBean for `RetriveDataSerive`.

Comment: @Lesiak
yes have added, sorry i forgot to add it in sample code.

This is how i have added,
`@MockBean private RetriveDataService retriveDataService;`

Comment: @M.Deinum,

Any specific way or example that i can follow. Would be a great help

Comment: @M.Deinum,

in fact, I do not agree with you what you said, because as i mentioned earlier if service layer do not have any bean injection its returning proper response.

Comment: A mock doesn't need dependencies.

Comment: @M.Deinum
Yes i agree, but it needs context in which it is executing and context has beans. If it return null it should always return null.

Comment: No it doesn't... What is in the context and which context depends on your test configuration... So you might end up for different tests with different instances of that service (or different mocks).

Comment: @M.Deinum
No.
Test configuration is what we specify on test class level(`@Mockbean` etc), hope you are talking about the same thing. And about ending up with multiple instances of services never happens, as its Springs application context and `@Mockbean` is bean representation in it.

Comment: When running multiple tests, each with a slightly different `@ContextConfiguration` (or different `@WebMvcTest`) that result in a new `ApplicationContext` being created. Each context having its own bean. Contexts are cached and can be reused IF the same `@ContextConfiguration` is used. Caching depends on config classes, listeners, `@TestPropertySource` etc. if one of those is different you get a new context and thus new bean.

Comment: @M.Deinum, Might be the case, but in my problem statement i have only one `ApplicationContext`(and `@ContextConfiguration`, `@WebMvcTest` for that matter). 

it would be really helpful to me, if you provide a reference link or example to follow and resolve this.

Comment: As stated add behavior to the mock. add an `@MockBean` to your test class, register behavior (return some object from your service using Mockito.when or BDDMockito). As mentioned if you don't the default is to return `null`. (From Mockito documentation -> **"By default, for all methods that return a value, a mock will return either `null`, a primitive/primitive wrapper value, or an empty collection, as appropriate. For example 0 for an int/Integer and false for a boolean/Boolean."**

Comment: @M.Deinum
I tried that, but same issue.

Comment: Then you haven't registered correctly and the predicate doesn't match what you actually passed in and hence it still returns null.

Comment: i tried all the possible ways that i can think of. Hope you have observed the output, it has status code 200 but other fields are null like content type, body etc.  And if it the case of what you mentioned, i would have got correct content type at least.

Comment: Note that `@WebMvcTest` creates not only your controller, but also all beans relevant in mvc context (like `@ControllerAdvice`). The error could have been handled by one of your `@ControllerAdvice` components. Have you debugged `TestController.myMethod` to check the answer from @M. Deinum ?

Comment: No you wouldn't get the correct content type as `null` isn't JSON and you will not get that content-type. It cannot be interpreted, and hence a lot is `null`. Your code doesn't show what you tried in registering behavior so what you did isn't visible to us.

Comment: @Lesiak

Yes, in short it creates web interfacing layer. right now i do not have any advice's, but on controller lever service is returning null even though it has correct service bean.

But you got a valid point, i should try with controller advice

Comment: @M.Deinum,

registering behavior is not mandatory. I am repeating it again, in my use case, **there are test cases where Service do not have any injected beans, and those are working fine**

Comment: @M.Deinum, sorry if i misunderstood, but in one of my previous comments i already told that i followed the documentation and registered the behavior, still i am facing same issue. I think you missed my multiple comments asking for reference of documentation that you referred or possibly a sample app that demonstrate this use case. 

I can try and then come back.

Comment: If you registered behavior and it didn't work, as I mentioned, then your predicate for matching the input isn't correct and then the default behavior still applies. I also requested for you to add the behavior you added to your post which you didn't do.

Comment: MyRequestModel requestModel = new MyRequestModel();
MyRequestModel responseModel = new MyRequestModel();
given(retriveDataService.retriveData(requestModel)).willReturn(responseModel);

it is something similar,@M.Deinum

Comment: Have you overridden `MyRequestModel.equals`? If so, is the object you deserialize in `TestController.myMethod` equal to one you use when specifying mock behaviour?

Comment: @Lesiak, no i have not overridden it. And also my Controller advice is not catching any exceptions.

Comment: Then you have 2 approaches - either override equals or learn about argument matchers

Comment: @Lesiak, sure i will try.

this the [repo](https://github.com/parshuram-patil/testing-with-mockito) where i tried simulating the exact use case and it is reproducible(may be i missed something in hurry).

testPostUsingNestedService() is the test that is failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking your repository confirmed assumption form the discussion in comments under question.

You specify expectations on your mock

```
MyModel requestMessage = new MyModel();
requestMessage.setMessage("Hello Request Post");
given(testService1.getMessage(requestMessage)).willReturn(responseMessage);
```

but the message received to in your controller in your `@WebMvcTest` is not equal to requestMessage specified in the test. This is due to the fact that `MyModel` class does not override `equals` method.
In this situation, Mockito will use its default behaviour:

> By default, for all methods that return a value, a mock will return either null, a primitive/primitive wrapper value, or an empty collection, as appropriate. For example 0 for an int/Integer and false for a boolean/Boolean.

You have two options to fix the problem:

1. override `equals` (and `hashCode`) in your request class.
2. Get acquainted with argument matchers

More info on option 2.:

Technically, your expectation is equivalent to:

```
given(testService1.getMessage(ArgumentMatchers.eq(requestMessage)))
  .willReturn(responseMessage);
```

You can use other matcher, or even define your own. This is useful if you cannot modify code of your argument's type (type coming from 3-rd party library etc).
For example, you can use `ArgumentMatchers.any(MyModel.class))`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, i think we are closer to the solution. But i tried the way you suggested and my observation is, its only working when i do `given(testService1.getMessage(ArgumentMatchers.any(MyModel.class))).willReturn(responseMessage);` and i think its obvious. Please find the updated code in git [repository](https://github.com/parshuram-patil/testing-with-mockito/commits/master).

Comment: yayy, finally It worked. it was silly mistake in override method.@Lesiak thank you very much

Comment: FYI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58129028/string-comparison-with-not-working-in-mockito

Comment: @Psp360 It is a good thing that you leaned how to implement equals and hashCode manually. Good IDE can generate them for you (at least for non-circular data structures)

Comment: Yes, i had never used it with mockito. But there also have a observation, please have a look. Link is in the previous comment.